# How to add tsconfig to razor class library nuget package

Tags: typescript, msbuild, nuget, blazor, .net-6.0

I have created razor class library and added

- Typescript/tsconfig.json
- Typescript/scripts.ts
- PackageReference to `Microsoft.TypeScript.MSBuild`

When I reference the project in my app using ProjectReference, it works fine.

**When I reference it using PackageReference, I'm getting weird build error:**

> tsc : error TS18003: Build:No inputs were found in config file 'C:/Users/danie/.nuget/packages/mypackage/0.5.0/contentFiles/any/net6.0/Typescript/tsconfig.json'. Specified 'include' paths were '["**/*"]' and 'exclude' paths were '["../wwwroot"]'. [C:\Projects\app\App.csproj]

1. How do I properly include typescript in razor class library, so that I can create valid nuget package from it?
2. Why is the `dotnet build app.csproj` event attempting to build typescript located in nuget package?

---

This is my MyPackage.csproj

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Razor">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework
    <GeneratePackageOnBuild>True</GeneratePackageOnBuild>
    <PackageId>MyPackage</PackageId>
    <EmbedUntrackedSources>true</EmbedUntrackedSources>
  </PropertyGroup>
  
  <ItemGroup>
    <SupportedPlatform Include="browser" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.SourceLink.GitHub" Version="1.0.0" PrivateAssets="All" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web" Version="6.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.TypeScript.MSBuild" Version="4.5.3">
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
    </PackageReference>
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Folder Include="wwwroot\" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Answer (score 1):

I got this working by adding the following block to my csproj file of the razor class library.

```
<Target Name="RemoveTSConfigFileFromPackage" AfterTargets="CompileTypeScriptWithTSConfig">
    <ItemGroup>
        <Content Remove="**\tsconfig.json" />
    </ItemGroup>
</Target>
```

This removes the tsconfig.json from the nuget package when it is built and avoids the build errors in the consuming project.

See this thread for further information: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/2166